# Reduce lookups for rarely changing information in the footer / header in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization

I have an optimization question. This is not my situation but for the purposes of the question this example fits better:

Let's say you have an app that displays your monthly specials. That information rarely changes - once a month. It display 5 specials, but each special needs to a display info like this:

```
Product.name
Product.manufacturer.name
Store.shipping_address.address_line_1
Store.shipping_address.address_line_1
Store.shipping_address.city
Store.shipping_address.state
Store.shipping_address.zip
Store.phone_number.area_code
Store.phone_number.phone_number
```

With properly setup associations, you'll end up doing 5 queries to a db. ( 1 to pull all the specials, 1 for address, 1 for phone, 1 for product, 1 for manufacturer).
In this example - shipping_address and phone_number, are methods setup in Store model, that do lookups on polymorphic models of Address and Phone number that have a 1 to many relationship to a model Category ( hold info like shipping vs billing , or phone vs. fax)

Here is the problem, let's say you have 5 specials, and they may be in various stores, so you need to do 5 queries on each page to display this info, including the front page.

What would be the best way to optimize this / speed it up?

Comment: Read up on `:include`, it should take you 5 queries regardless of how many parent records are returned.

Comment: you are right. I don't know why I wrote 21. I do know what include is and how to use it thou. Corrected post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is that you do need to retrieve this data at some point--there's no getting around that. But, you can minimize the number of queries using eager loading and caching.

Here's the official guide to eager loading:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Eager loading will minimize the number of queries, but you're still hitting the database. So, to avoid running those queries on each request, I would definitely cache the data at some level. Rails offers various caching strategies. Fragment caching might be an excellent solution here. Here are more details on caching:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Sorry If I didn't calrify my question, I'm not worried  about the fact that I need to hit db at some point and I minimized # of queries already. I was mostly looking to see if there is anythig else I can do besides caching.